# Delete mySQL database rows based on a dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, database, pandas, sqlalchemy

Let us say I have a dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame({"company" : ['abc','def','xyz'], 
                                "amount": [1,1,1]})
```

I want to remove (from a mySQL database) N rows that match 'company' values from a database, N being the number listed on the "amount" column, looping through the dataframe rows one at a time, deleting the amount listed from the DB

So, if I have a database that looks like this

```
   company   Broke?
1    abc      Yes
2    abc      Yes 
3    def      No
4    xyz      Yes
5    abc      No
6    lmn      Yes
```

And I pass the original dataframe deleting one of each (because 'amount' is always 1) I should get this result on my DB

```
   company   Broke?
2    abc      Yes 
5    abc      No
6    lmn      Yes
```

Note that in case of multiple records I want to delete just the first one in the order they have been stored in the first place